# How to get the metadata of a mysql table on sailsjs

Tags: mysql, model, sails.js, waterline, database-metadata

I was wondering if you can get the metadata or the entire structure of the table and columns using sailsjs or waterline's mysql module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of searching, I've finally found the holy grail. Well half of the holy grail.
Anyway, I just followed the instructions given here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/780 then created my own custom query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its very easy to get structure of MySQL table by Waterline SalsJS...

```
Model.query("desc table_name",function (err, models) {
        if(!err)
          {
              //Do somethng wth your data in models variable
          }
      }
    )
```

Here **table_name** is your table name

For me, below code was working fine...

```
db('users_table').query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM users_table",function (err, models) {
        if (! err )
            // working with data
      });
```